# python last element change to different format

Tags: python, loops

i have a list such as this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I want to loop through it with python code, and properly format it to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. The following is the code that i am using to execute the loop

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for x in lst:
    print "%s,"%x
```

This is the return value
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,`

Can python pick up the last element of the loop and change the format of the loop?

Comment: Don't use ```list``` as a variable name. ```list``` is a builtin python type. You shouldn't override it.

Comment: I don't think that's the "return" (printed) value from the code you posted.  Did you forget a trailing comma?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join` but you will need to change the `int`s to strings:

```
print ','.join(str(x) for x in lst)
```

Comment: You can dump the brackets on the list comprehension and just make it a generator expression.  Or `','.join(map(str,lst))`.

Comment: Should also change `list` to `lst`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a separator and join the list:

```
print ", ".join(str(x) for x in lst)
```

Also, I recommend not hiding the builtin name `list` and call your numbers something else.

Comment: I wish downvoters would explain.  Maybe because of the `", "` instead of `","` and the use of `list` after saying not to use `list`.

Comment: I had missed the str(x) in my first answer, that's probably why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly loop through it, and not print the space:

```
import sys
my_list = range(1,10+1) 
for x in my_list:
    sys.stdout.write("%s," % x)
```

or

```
>>> my_list = range(1,10+1) 
>>> print ','.join(map(str, my_list)) + ','
```

where the last `+ ','` is necessary to have a comma at the very end.

The word `list` is a builtin in python, so you should avoid naming variables `list` as that will remove the keyword from the namespace.

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> print a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> print list(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> type(a) == list
False
>>> type(list(a)) == list
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> str(lst)[1:-1]
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10'
```

Comment: I think OP also wants to omit spaces:  `str(lst)[1:-1].replace(' ', '')`